# If $a^3=a$ in a ring, prove: the ring is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, not necessarily with a unit element. $R$ is not necessarily integral.
If for any $a \in R$, $a^3=a$, prove: $R$ is commutative:
Any $a, b  \in R$, $ab=ba$.

My efforts on it:
I can use the relation $(a+b)^3=a+b$ and $(a-b)^3=a-b$. But the relation is cubic and I do not know how to reduce it to a relation about $ab$ and $ba$.

Comment: see particularly the answer to that question, which is not specific to matrices.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be (temporarily) closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You may refer to [this link](http://www.mateforum.ro/articole/jacobson.pdf).

Comment: http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?&f=21&p=63609&t=16476#p63609

Comment: This is an old result by Herstein, on the same vein as Boolean rings ($a^2=a$, for all $a$). A theorem by Jacobson generalizes both: if, for any element $a\in R$ there exist an integer $n(a)>1$ such that $a^{n(a)}=a$, then $R$ is commutative.

Answer (score 4):

This is a cute problem that one can find in Herstein's book on Algebra.

Start by proving that if $xy=0$, then $yx=0$. 
Then,let us begin by noting that if $x^2=x$, then we have that $yx=xy$. This follows since 
$x^2y-xy=x(xy-y)=x(y-y)=0$, and then $(xy-y)x=0$, so that $xyx = yx$. You can do it in a similar way for $(y-yx)x$ to show it is zero and deduce that $xy = xyx$ and as such, $xy=yx$.

Now, we have that for any $x \in R$, we have that $x^2$ satisfies $(x^2)^2=x^4=x^2$. So, $x^2$ commutes with any element of R. We have that $(x+x^2)$ commutes with every element of R too. Indeed, we have that $(x+x^2)^2 = 2(x+x^2)$. You can show that if $y \in R$ satisifes $y^2 = n y$, then y commutes with any element of R.

Now, finish by using the identity $(x+x^2)-x^2=x$ and that the sum of elements that commutes with any element of R commutes with any element of R.

Comment: thanks very much. I found this problem in Kostrikin's Introduction to Algebra